# Excel files are not opening in excel client application : Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, ie, modern-document-library, modern-experience

We are trying to open excel files in excel client application but when we click on "open in excel" option then nothing is happening. We having latest IE and office 2013 installed.

This issue is only in **modern list experience**. In classic mode files are opening in excel client application.

Comment: I'm having the same, or at least a similar, problem.
I'll try to describe and hopefully it'll help someone give us a lead... 1. in modern list experience if clicking the title - the document opens in online excel editor
2. in modern list experience if trying to select "Open in Excel" from the context menu - nothing happens
3. in classic view when clicking the title - nothing happens
4. in classic view when selecting "Open in Excel" the document opens in Excel on client. The site collection is set to use "open in client software" as default. Anyone solve this issue? Also:
it seems to be compute